# How can i get token from Header in Retrofit in Android

Tags: android, retrofit2

In my application I should **get** users info from `json` and I should get **token** from **header of request**.
I can get `json` and show this data but I don't know how can I get token from header?
in my application I should get token from header, and send again this token with header to server.
In header of request, key is token . (my mean is, token name is key).

For server requests I use `Retrofit2` and with this library I can **GET** and **POST** methods, **but I don't know** how can I get and post token (key) from header.

How can I it?

Comment: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header

Comment: @quicklearner, can you send me simple project for this help? I am amateur

Comment: @quicklearner, please, I am amateur and I need this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Angel M the link from quick learner explains how to add custom headers to your requests but not how to retrieve them. To get a header value you can use the below code:

```
String headerValue = response.headers().get("headerName");
  if(headerValue != null){
      //use your header value
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man, I use this code but not show me any value from headerValue  !!! how can I fix it?

Comment: I think this code should work, maybe the server is not returning the header you want. You can try to logging the headers you're receiving to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

String token = response.headers().get("key");

Comment: Thanks man, I use this code but not show me any value from headerValue !!! how can I fix it?

Comment: is the name of the key for your token "key"? can you share the header in the response?